# File name maybe incorrect on Web config, how to fix this exception?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have this error, it gets thrown during registration on my mvc application. How do i fix this issue? Below is my Web.Config file for connectionString.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name = "eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString = "Data Source=GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=[DataDirectory]\eNtsaOnlineRegistra[enter image description here][1]tionDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistration; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>


public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.ConfirmedEmail = false;
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); ?/** Error thrown here and shown the screen shot image as attached.***/
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                        new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ggcobani@gmail.com", "Web Registration"),
                        new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(user.Email));
                    m.Subject = "Email confirmation";
                    m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Thank you for your registration, please click on the below link to complete your registration: <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">{1}</a>", user.UserName, Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Token = user.Id, Email = user.Email }, Request.Url.Scheme));
                    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mydomain.com");
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ggcobani@gmail.com", "password");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(m);
                    return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Account", new { Email = user.Email });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Just type the correct path. `eNtsaOnlineRegistra[enter image description here][1]tionDB.mdf` is obviously an invalid. Did someone paste the wrong string there? Was this supposed to be `eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf`? Or did you paste an image tag inside the code snippet while writing the question?

Comment: Assuming the image markdown was added by mistake while writing the question, what error do you get? What does `I have this error, it gets thrown during registration on my mvc application.` mean? What registration?

Comment: Its complaining about the path, i changed <connectionStrings>
    <add name = "eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString = "Data Source=GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= |DataDirectory|\eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistration; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>. Now i am getting new exception saying its already exist after running my sql server to local account from Services on Control Panel(before Access Denied).
  </connectionStrings>